# When I mouseover on child How to prevent to trigger mouseover on parent on React.Js

Tags: reactjs, onmouseover, onmouseout

https://codesandbox.io/s/mmk8w39l49

this is my simple copy of my app using `OnMouseOver`

there're parent box(Card.jsx, skyblue color box) and child box(Container.jsx yellow color box) that has mouseover, mousedown, mouseout and for each box it has menu bar that if hover pop real menu bar but when after mouseover on box whenever I mouseover menu bar some error break out ( parent mouseout and menu bar mouseover occurs 3 times )

When I mouseover on menu bar I want not to occur mouseout of box

maybe

```
{this.state.hover || this.state.active ? (
      <div>
        {this.state.toolHover ? (
          <div
            onMouseOut={this.handleOnMouseOutTool}
            style={{
              ...toolStyle,
              transition: "opacity 0.5s ease",
              opacity: this.state.toolHover ? "1" : "0"
            }}
          >
            <button
              style={{
                ...buttonStyle,
                borderTopLeftRadius: "100%",
                borderBottomLeftRadius: "100%"
              }}
            />
            <button style={buttonStyle} />
            <button style={buttonStyle} />
          </div>
        ) : (
          <div
            onMouseOver={this.handleOnMouseOverTool}
            style={{
              ...handleStyle
            }}
          />
        )}
      </div>
    ) : null}
```

this style of code make some error, but I have no idea how to solve it

Comment: I think you should probably describe the problem, e.g., what's supposed to happen, what actually happens, etc.

Comment: Yes, and also please edit your question to include the relevant parts of your code. Links to code examples are OK, but should not be the only source of code

Comment: Thank you for your advice! I edit my question more specifically